# GIFs returned by API are not animated

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am attempting to return animated GIFs via my ASP.NET Core API, but only some returned GIFs actually animate. The ones that do not work show only the first frame and never animate, the ones that work are played like normal gifs. I cannot figure out why some work and others do not. All are returned with `Content-Type: image/gif`, and `Content-Length` is set correctly. My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

---

Some example images:

- [This one](https://i.imgur.com/Emgu5Dy.gif) does not work.
- [This one](https://i.imgur.com/w9smBPq.gif) does not work.
- [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9PbA.gif) does work.
- [This one](https://i.imgur.com/iZWX9VT.gif) does work.

*(For the record, this is just a small side project to get some more experience with MVC Core. I'm not trying to bypass imgur's ads.)*

---

Chrome throws this in the console on all images, regardless of whether they animate or not.

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/gif: "localhost:22222/filename.gif".
```

---

My code:

```cs
var img = await _client.GetStreamAsync("http://my.url");

// necessary to get the correct content length
var contents = new MemoryStream();
await img.CopyToAsync(contents);

Response.ContentLength = contents.Length;
contents.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(contents, "image/gif");
```

Comment: It looks like whatever is `http://my.url` is returning a document and not a gif.

Comment: @Dealdiane: i was thinking the same but the OP mentions some work and some dont

Comment: @vaindil: ARe you able to link a couple of GIFs that WORK and a couple that DONT?

Comment: @garfbradaz I've added example images to the post, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with imgur. It serves different versions of .gif files depending on the content being requested and possibly based on the user agent or referrer or other parts of the request. They will similarly redirect GIFs to their .gifv player/compatibility page in order to avoid serving large files. If you look at the actual content being served, you should see that it's either giving you HTML for said page or it's serving the non-animated thumbnail version of the GIF. (You can see that version manually by adding an 'h' to the end of the image ID in the URL - for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZaR7.jpg.)

The two that don't work have two things in common: They were created via imgur's vidgif tool, and they're both over 30MB in size. The other two were both uploaded as .gif files and don't exceed 15MB. Whatever the differences or imgur's logic, it must result in something going wrong on the HTML player page or imgur giving you the thumbnail version for just the vidgif ones.

It's possible that using a normal browser user agent in your request will change this behavior.

If it matters, you might be better off getting the .mp4 version. There won't be one for every GIF - your third example won't have one since it's very small. You can fall back to .gif (or .jpg) for those cases.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. I switched to the mp4 version for most of them (with a gif fallback) and things are working smoothly. Thank you!